# how to solve the displaying scrollable view pager under actionbar in the following code?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

i am trying to display scroll view through view pager but when i am trying to execute it's just displaying blank page with background color.it does not reflecting on the screen..actually i have few activities in my project.i want to display my view pager under the action bar menu.here some problem is there..when i am executing the view pager in separate activity it's working very nicely.but when i am trying  run it through my original activities it's not working fine.please show me solution.here is my code.

```
    public class SlideViewActivity extends FragmentActivity {
static final int NUM_ITEMS = 6;
ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;
public static final Integer[] IMAGE_NAME = {R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image3,
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_page);
    imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
}

public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
        return SwipeFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}

public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
        Integer imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[position];
        int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(imageFileName), "drawable", "com.javapapers.android.swipeimageslider");
        imageView.setImageResource(imgResId);
        //container.addView(swipeView);
        return swipeView;
    }

    static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return swipeFragment;
    }


}}
```

menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.brahmaiah.demo_proj_filpkart.MenuActivity">
<!--tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"-->

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my view pager supporting through xml
fragment_page.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

please go through it .and give a way

Answer (score 0):

please move :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

to activity.xml above viewpager and change viewpager height and width to match_parent

Comment: even though the problem continues.nothing is happening